# How to get the sum of a list of numbers stored in a Cucumber Feature File data table in Cypress framework?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

In my Cucumber/Cypress test framework, I am trying to add a list of numbers together. They are defined in the below Feature File:

```
 When add the following pokemon to my cart
     | pokemonName | price |
     | bulbasaur   | 64    |
     | ivysaur     | 142   |
     | venusaur    | 263   |
```

Here is my Step Definition:

```
When('I add the following pokemon to my cart', (dataTable) => {
  let totalAmount;
  dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem => {
    totalAmount += elem.price
  });
  cy.log(totalAmount)
});
```

Actual Result:
When I run this test, the `totalAmount` value logged is `64142263`.

Expected Result:
I want the actual result to be the sum of the 3 prices - `469`

I understand what the code is doing is appending the values together as strings, but I want to know how I can treat these values as numbers, so I can get the sum of them combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress is most likely returning the text as a string instead of a number. When using `+=` with a string, it will addend the string to the current string (`'123' += '456' => '123456'`) instead of actually adding the numbers.

You could simply cast the text returned to a Number, if you did not want to use the unary plus operator.

```js
...
totalAmount += Number(ele.price)
...
```

If picking this approach, it would probably be helpful to define a type for `totalAmount`

Answer (score 1):

I never used Cucumber/Cypress but it looks like your totalAmount is the concatenation of your price values (=> price is considered as a string).
You should try using the unary plus operator :

```js
totalAmount = +totalAmount + +elem;
```